# $N_1N_2N_3=\{x\in F^{\times}| x^2\in N\}$

Tags: galois-theory, normed-spaces, galois-extensions

> Let $E/F$ be a Galois extension of fields with Galois group $G=\{1,\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3\}\simeq (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2$. Let $F_i=E^{\sigma_i}$ and $N_i=N_{F_i/F}(F_i^{\times})$. Show that $N_1N_2N_3=\{x\in F^{\times}| x^2\in N\}$, where $N=N_{E/F}(E^{\times})$.

I have no idea about this problem. Any hints are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: One direction follows from the identity $$(N_{F_1/F}(x_1)N_{F_2/F}(x_2)N_{F_3/F}(x_3))^2=N_{E/F}(x_1x_2x_3).$$ I'm ashamed to admit that I don't see the other direction right away at all. The sign information lost when squaring $x$ is a non-problem, as we always have $-1\in N_1N_2N_3$. That may help, but I'm missing the big idea :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The previous answer was very, very wrong, but I finally managed to find a fix. The old answer is at the end for legacy, but the valid proof is as follows:

First, by the identity in Jyrki Lahtonen’s comment, $(N_1N_2N_3)^2 \subset N$, entailing $LHS \subset RHS$.

Now, let $x \in F^{\times}$ be such that $N_{E/F}(z)=x^2$ for some nonzero $z \in E$. Let $1 \leq i \leq 3$, let $j \neq i$ be between $1,2,3$, and note that $\frac{N_{E/F_i}(z)}{x} \in F_i$ has norm $1$ over $F$.

As $F_i/F$ is quadratic with only nonzero automorphism $\sigma_j$, by ”Hilbert 90” there exists $y_i \in F_i$ such that $\frac{z\sigma_i(z)}{x}=\frac{y_i}{\sigma_j(y_i)}$.

By taking $i=1,3$, $j=2$ in both equations, and taking the quotient of the two equations, it follows $\frac{\sigma_1(z)}{\sigma_2\circ \sigma_1(z)}=\frac{(y_1/y_3)}{\sigma_2(y_1/y_3)}$, which entails $\frac{y_1}{y_3}\in F_2 \sigma_1(z)$.

Now, by taking cyclic product, it follows $1=\frac{y_1}{y_3}\frac{y_3}{y_2}\frac{y_2}{y_1} \in F_1F_2F_3\sigma_1(z)\sigma_2(z)\sigma_3(z)=F_1F_2F_3\frac{x^2}z$, and therefore $z \in F_1F_2F_3$.

By the identity in Jyrki Lahtonen’s comment, it follows $x^2 \in (N_1N_2N_3)^2$, hence $x$ or $-x$ is in $N_1N_2N_3$. To conclude, we only need to show that $-1 \in N_1N_2N_3$, as stated in Jyrki Lahtonen’s comment.

We treat the case where the characteristic is not $2$ (it’s obvious otherwise).

Let $j \neq i$. $\sigma_j$ is a nontrivial $F$-linear symmetry of $F_i$ so has an eigenvector for $-1$, which we denote as $u_i$. Note that $u_i$ is also a $-1$-eigenvector for the last element of $G$ ( which acts as $\sigma_j$). Therefore $\sigma_3(u_1u_2)=(-u_1)(-u_2)=u_1u_2$, and $\sigma_1(u_1u_2)=u_1(-u_2)=-u_1u_2$, so we can take $u_3=\frac{1}{u_1u_2}$.

Now, $N_{F_1/F}(u_1)N_{F_2/F}(u_2)N_{F_3/F}(u_3)=(-u_1^2)(-u_2^2)(-u_3^2)=-1$ and we are done.

Old answer:

Write $$y=\left(\frac{\sigma_2(y)}{\sigma_1(y)}\right)(y\sigma_1(y))(\sigma_1(y)\sigma_3(y))\left(\frac{1}{\sigma_1(y)\sigma_2(y)}\right).$$

It follows that if $K =\{x \in E^{\times},\, N_{E/F}(x)=1\}$, $E=KF_1^{\times}F_2^{\times}F_3^{\times}$.

As a consequence, for a given $x \in F^{\times}$, $x \in N$ iff $x \in N_{E/F}(F_1^{\times}F_2^{\times}F_3^{\times})$, iff (by the identity in Jyrki Lahtonen’s comment) $x \in (N_1N_2N_3)^2$.

It remains to show, to conclude, that, as stated in Jyrki Lahtonen’s comment, $-1 \in N_1N_2N_3$. We treat the case where the characteristic is not $2$ (it’s obvious otherwise).

Let $j \neq i$. $\sigma_j$ is a nontrivial $F$-linear symmetry of $F_i$ so has an eigenvector for $-1$, which we denote as $u_i$. Note that $u_i$ is also a $-1$-eigenvector for the last element of $G$ ( which acts as $\sigma_j$). Therefore $\sigma_3(u_1u_2)=(-u_1)(-u_2)=u_1u_2$, and $\sigma_1(u_1u_2)=u_1(-u_2)=-u_1u_2$, so we can take $u_3=\frac{1}{u_1u_2}$.

Now, $N_{F_1/F}(u_1)N_{F_2/F}(u_2)N_{F_3/F}(u_3)=(-u_1^2)(-u_2^2)(-u_3^2)=-1$ and we are done.

Comment: I see how the factor in the first parens has norm one, the factor in the second parens is a fixed point of $\sigma_1$, the third factor of $\sigma_2$ and the last factor is a fixed point of  $\sigma_3$. But try as I may, I get the r.h.s. to come out as $y\sigma_3(y)$ rather just $y$.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: oh, crap. I’m trying to work on a fix.

Comment: No, I don’t deserve the bounty, the comment above is right. I don’t have a fix and the proof is dangerously wrong.

Comment: Whew. Finally managed to find a good argument. I hope that one is sound.

Comment: Thank you for the extra effort :-)